# How do I install elementary OS?

Tags: system-installation

I would like to see a full how-to on installing the latest stable version of elementary OS.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that the majority of this information is already covered in the elementary [installation guide](https://elementary.io/docs/installation) that appears when you download.

---

Click all images to view a bigger version.

[image]

### Step 1 - Downloading

First, download the file - it will be a `.iso` from [elementary.io](http://elementary.io).

[image]

If you know you have a newer computer with a 64-bit processor, choose the 64-bit version.

If your computer is older or you do not know which type of processor your computer has, choose the 32-bit version. (64-bit processors will still be able to run this version).

[image]

### Step 2 - Writing to the bootable media.

When it has finished downloading, you need to either write it to a DVD or a USB. Only use a USB if you are sure your BIOS (the first screen you see when you boot) supports it.

#### For booting with a USB (recommended):

Download and install Unetbootin and open it up. It will look like this:

[image]

Click the radio button next to Diskimage and then click the `...` button to navigate to the `.iso` file you just downloaded.

[image]

insert the USB - make sure *it is the only USB plugged in*. Then select it from the Drive dropdown:

[image]

For me the USB I want to use is `/dev/sdd1`. Now click OK. It will go through the 4 steps:

[image] [image] [image]

You can either click Reboot Now or Exit at this point.

#### For booting with a CD (not recommended):

> **Burning from Windows**
>
> Windows 7/8/8.1
>
> Right-click on an ISO image and choose “Burn disc image”.
>
> [image]
>
> Select a drive and press "Burn".
>
> [image]
>
> If you check “Verify disc after burning”, it will verify that the ISO image has been burned correctly

> **Burning from Mac OS X**
>
> Launch Disk Utility (Applications → Utilities → Disk Utility).
>
> Insert your blank CD/DVD.
>
> Drag and drop your `.iso` file to the left pane in Disk Utility. Now both the blank disc and the `.iso` should be listed.
>
> Select the `.iso` file, and click on the Burn button in the tool bar.
>
> [image]
>
> Ensure that the "Verify burned data" check box is ticked (you may need to click on the disclosure triangle to see the check box).
>
> Click on Burn. The data will be burned and verified.
>
> [image]

> **Burning from Ubuntu**
>
> Right click on the `.iso` file and click "Write to Disc". Click Burn.

[Source](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto)

### Step 3 - Booting

Insert the DVD or USB and restart.

#### Booting on a PC

As your computer boots up, press the button to access the BIOS:

[image]

Change the order to have either DVD or USB - depending on which you used, and then save and exit the BIOS.

#### Booting on a Mac:

After you hear the chime, press and hold Option. Then, select the appropriate boot drive. Note that it *may* be incorrectly identified as "Windows", but this is normal.

---

It will then boot to a screen like this:

[image]

### Step 4 - Installing

Select Install elementary.

[image]

Confirm you have that is needed (6.5 GB disk space and internet connection).

I'd advise not to download updates (it slows down the install), but I would suggest the third-party software so you can place MP3s and such like and click continue.

Chose which install method you want - to install along side your current OS or to wipe it. You can also manually change the partitions by clicking something else.

Chose your location (this will set your time).

[image]

Now chose your keyboard - you can auto detect it if you want, this will auto select it.

[image]

Next chose your name, computer name, username and password:

[image]

Then click continue and it will install it:

[image]

This can take a long time - 30 minutes or more sometimes. Be patient, and don't power off the computer. It's recommended to keep a laptop plugged in for the duration of the install process.

### Step 5 - Use elementary OS

Finally, when it is installed it will ask you to reboot.

[image]

When it boots up, go into the BIOS again and change the boot order back to your Hard Drive first. It should boot pretty quickly:

[image]

And then you can login and start using it!

It is likely that you will have a lot of downloads to install, and when they have finished it will request a restart. Do this as soon as possible as they could include security updates.

#### Any more questions? Feel free to click Ask Question in the Top Right corner.

Comment: @Tim that's ok but your explaining looked like encouraging. If people are decided it to download it without paying even $1, they'll either find a way to do it or ask how it's done (here or at Google+). If the latter occurs, then we explain how, and we also explain why it is important *albeit not mandatory* to give as much as you can or think it's fair, even if it's a little.

Answer (score 3):

While simply linking is discouraged, in this instance there is a large, official [installation guide](https://elementary.io/docs/installation) that covers many options and will be kept up to date there.

Comment: Yes, there is. However I think it is worthwhile to have a Q&A as a duplicate target - it gets asked often enough. http://askubuntu.com/questions/linked/6328?sort=newest

Comment: Also see http://paste.ubuntu.com/11852113/