# How to install latest version of elementary OS along with windows and Ubuntu

Tags: system-installation

I am using windows 8 and Ubuntu 14.04.I would like to install elementary OS.I found a link related to installation  [how-do-i-install-elementary-os](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/357/how-do-i-install-elementary-os).But that seems not much useful for dual boot(here triple).

Question:

- How to install elementary OS as per partition table.

[image: Imgur]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was successfully Installed on Unallocated space by using `something else` option.

Added `swap area` and `/root`

[image: Imgur]