# Currently running Ubuntu and Windows dual boot - will installation overwrite both partitions?

Tags: system-installation

I'm currently running a dual-boot system with Windows Vista and Ubuntu. I'm just wondering if the 'erase disk' option will effectively erase both operating systems.

Comment: yes it will. See [here](https://elementaryos.stackexchange.com/questions/2398/how-to-install-latest-version-of-elementary-os-along-with-windows-and-ubuntu), if useful :)

Answer (score 1):

You can choose how you install elementary OS. In the installer, you will probably have these choices :

- Erase Ubuntu and reinstall : Install elementary in the ubuntu partition
- Erase disk and install : Take the full disk only for elementary
- Something else.

Something else will bring you in a partitionning tool. You have to reduce one of your existing partitions and create a new one if you want to install elementary OS + Ubuntu + Windows (I personally don't recommend this, if you do, be careful with grub.)

Answer (score 0):

"Erase disk" option will delete all the partitions on your harddrive, and create new ones for Elementary.

This means that Windows and Ubuntu would be completely removed, as well as any other data files you might have, and Elementary will be the only Operating System on your PC

Answer (score 0):

Both the question and answers are old. But, if I understand them to today's version....on the install screen that lists the partitions on my hard drive there is a drop down selector under the list that lists the partitions again with the prompt: Device for boot loader installation:
is this where I can select the partition with the unwanted OS and that is where elementary will be installed?

Thanks for any help